# Activity transition effects: slide in for the top activity and scale for the bottom activity

Tags: android, xml, animation

I want to achieve the effect displayed below. The effect is from Facebook.

[image: effect]

I have tried this in **Activity A**:

```
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_left_to_right, R.anim.scale_out);
```

And in **Activity B**:

```
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_right_to_left, R.anim.scale_in);
```

Where the xml are displayed below:

**R.anim.anim_left_to_right**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" 
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" 
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

**R.anim.anim_right_to_left**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

**R.anim.scale_out**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <scale android:fromXScale="1.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0"
            android:toXScale="1.0"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:duration="500"
            android:fillBefore="false" />
</set>
```

**R.anim.scale_in**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <scale android:fromXScale="1.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0"
            android:toXScale="0.8"
            android:toYScale="0.8"
            android:duration="500"
            android:fillBefore="false" />
</set>
```

However, it does not achieve the desired effect - for some reason, I can just not get this right. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Slower] [image: Faster]

Styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ....
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ActivityAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="ActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/activity_out</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_back_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/activity_back_out</item>
</style>
```

**activity_in.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime">
    </translate>
</set>
```

**activity_out.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.84"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.84"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="8%"
        android:toXDelta="16%"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.25"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>

</set>
```

**activity_back_in.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.84"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.84"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="8%"
        android:fromXDelta="16%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.25"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>

</set>
```

**activity_back_out.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime">
    </translate>
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolai. It is actually working - i just put your classes into a test app and it appears to work fine. I have another question on the theme that is a follow up to this question , can you please help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207321/setting-style-androidwindowistranslucent-seems-to-conflict-with-windowanimation

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible to get this kind of animations with translucent activities because if you set "windowIsTranslucent" to true you can provide only "windowEnterAnimation" and "windowExitAnimation". Please have a look at https://gist.github.com/lassana/136cd637dafe872cc0f3