# Setting style android:windowIsTranslucent seems to conflict with windowAnimationStyle

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, android-theme

I have the following style on in my `style.xml` and is a follow up to my question here [Activity transition effects: slide in for the top activity and scale for the bottom activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104594/activity-transition-effects-slide-in-for-the-top-activity-and-scale-for-the-bot/36200860#36200860):

```
<style name="RevealTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ActivityAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="ActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/animation_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/animation_out</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/animation_back_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/animation_back_out</item>
</style>
```

I have found that the style `android:windowBackground`conflicts with `android:windowAnimationStyle` and the animation is not fully displaying. If I include the above style as is in my style.xml and run my app, I get the following:

[image]

If I comment out the lines here:

```
<style name="RevealTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> 
    <!--<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> COMMENTED OUT-->
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ActivityAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="ActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/animation_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/animation_out</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/animation_back_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/animation_back_out</item>
</style>
```

[image]

I don't understand why this is the case. I need the windowIsTranslucent for some of my other animations.

These are the xml animation class I'm using (thanks to Nikolai Doronin):

**activity_in.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime">
    </translate>
</set>
```

**activity_out.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.84"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.84"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="8%"
        android:toXDelta="16%"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.25"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>

</set>
```

**activity_back_in.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.84"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.84"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="8%"
        android:fromXDelta="16%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.25"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime"/>

</set>
```

**activity_back_out.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="@integer/activityAnimationTime">
    </translate>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, change

```
<style name="ActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation">
```

to

```
<style name="ActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Translucent">
```